# The most light-weight Compiz compatible environment?

Tags: window-manager, desktop-environment

I require Compiz for organizational reasons; I make heavy use of its window sorting features. But I like light-weight environments so that I can give as much of my system's resources to the applications as possible.

Is there a DE that plays nice with Compiz, but is still very light?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm running Compiz standalone right now. Works just fine. I followed the instructions [on the Arch Linux Compiz wiki page](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz); see especially the section [As a Standalone Window Manager](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz#As_a_Standalone_Window_Manager).

Comment: Cairo-Dock's working on a dock+compiz stand-alone too: http://glx-dock.org/bg_topic.php?t=5562

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually require a DE at all? I've run Compiz without one before, there's no real reason it would require one, and that's about as light-weight as you can get

Comment: Hmm... I never thought about that. Just compiz and a dock would be perfectly adequate for me!  edit: well, so long as I can have a functioning tray on my dock for wireless control and whatnot.