# How to remove GNOME to run only Compiz

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, compiz

Regarding [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1206/), I really like the idea of running Compiz without a desktop environment. I currently have Ubuntu 10.04 (with GNOME and Compiz) and want to give it a try. Now how can I configure my system to enable compiz running without GNOME (then I can remove it completely)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompizStandalone) is what you are looking for.

Comment: it wasn't in the top search results either, but some light digging found it okay.