# Distro- lightweight and easy to install

Tags: distributions, distribution-choice

Ubuntu was too slow on my computer and Arch installation had many problems too. Which distro do you recommend to me that's lightweight as well as easy to install?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should definitely give a second try to **Archlinux**...

It's slogan is: "*A simple, lightweight distribution*". You may object but in my opinion the installation of Arch is very simple and basic (just don't forget about the great and rich documentation available on wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/). I can install the whole system in less then half an hour and end with a flexible and featurefull working environment having a complete control over my system! With no versions problems (it is a rolling release distro) and with `pacman` -- a fantastic package manager that magically manages all the dependencies and other installation tasks in a simple and transparent way, archlinux is definitely worth a try!

If you want a clean, efficient and simple linux distribution which follows all the modern requirements archlinux is for you!

*Post-scriptum*: In case of any questions about arch you can directly contact me -- rizo[dot]isrof[at]gmai[dot]com ;)

Comment: I decided that too! :) Giving it a second try right now...

Comment: @infoquad: So, how is your Archlinux installation going? :)

Comment: @Rizo- Not very good :(

Comment: What's wrong? Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: I have hear Archlinux is one of the most difficult distro's to install.

Answer (score 5):

The Damn Small Linux project is dead.  The lead developer moved on to [Tiny Core Linux](http://www.tinycorelinux.com/)

Although the sub 30mb distros are probably too light weight for most purposes.  Something a little bit bigger might work as well.
[Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/)
[Crunchbang Linux](http://crunchbanglinux.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Consider [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), which aims to be the LXDE version of Ubuntu (though not get officially recognized by Canonical as an official offspin); much lighter weight than the standard one. (I also recommend Crunchbang, which has been covered already.)

Answer (score 4):

If you have an older computer, the important thing is not to use resource-hungry *applications* or *settings*. Gnome+compiz on Puppy Linux will be just as slow as on Ubuntu, if you manage to install it. Pick any distribution whose installer will run on your computer, and use a lightweight window manager. See for example [the lightest way to have a GUI in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/the-lightest-way-to-have-a-gui-in-linux), [How to get rid of desktop environment and use a window manager only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/how-to-get-rid-of-desktop-environment-and-use-a-window-manager-only).

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [SliTaz](http://www.slitaz.org/)? It is a very lightweight (~30MB) distribution with a very easy to use package manager, a new version is due out soon. The entire OS can be loaded into RAM which makes it extremely fast. Installation is very quick and simple, plus there's a very helpful forum. Here's the official feature list:

- Root filesystem taking up about 100
  MB and ISO image of less than 30 MB.
- Ready to use Web server powered by
  LightTPD with CGI and PHP support.
- Browse the Web with Midori or Retawq
  in text mode.
- Sound support provided by Alsa mixer,
  audio player and CD ripper/encoder.
- Chat, mail and FTP clients.
- SSH client and server powered by
  Dropbear.
- Database engine with SQLite.
- Generate a LiveUSB device.
- Tools to create, edit or burn CD or
  DVD images.
- Elegant desktop with Openbox running
  on the top of Xorg/Xvesa (X server).
- Homemade graphical boxes to command
  line utilities.
- 2300 packages easily installable from
  the mirror.
- Active and friendly community.

I've used it myself and like it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are many but this is the one that immediately comes to my mind: [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)

EDIT: I also found this article about light weight distros: [What's the best lightweight Linux distro?](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/whats-best-lightweight-linux-distro)

Also you can try switching to Xfce instead of GNOME as your desktop environment. Xfce is lot lighter than GNOME/KDE.