# Damn Small Linux on EEE PC 901

Tags: small-distribution, ssd, netbook, asus

Has anyone tried to use (either install to HD or LiveUSB) Damn Small Linux on the Asus EEE PC 901 netbook? If so, does it work well? Does it have any problem with the WiFi connection?.

I ask because the Asus EEE PC 901 netbook has SSD drives and I do not know if the DSL has support for such discs. Also, I know that the WiFi connection EEE PC 901 has problems on some systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn Small Linux is **OLD** (kernel 2.4). You should choose another distribution. Take a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5733/2661).

Comment: Do you know any linux light-distribution (like Archlinux, Puppy linux, etc) that works well on Asus EEE PC 901?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to run any distribution on this netbook (there was some versions with Linux preinstalled). Unfortunately I don't have any details about that. Personally I would try to install Debian on it with some lightwight WM.

Comment: Had good success today with [BunsenLabs](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/) Linux Helium (based on Debian 9, so, it's recent). And very lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu or Suse distro to prevent driver problems. You can do minimal installs with those systems as well. Choose a minimal or base install, then add the needed packages after.

Comment: Indeed, I am also considering this option. But if you perform a basic installation (in some distributions you mentioned) you can not install the appropriate drivers and the system does not work well, right?.

Comment: Incorrect, in all of the distro's listed above, you can add the additional kernel drivers, etc. at any time. I have never run into a limitation like the one you describe.

Comment: No problem. Hope it goes well for you. ;)