# Graphical applications in terminal

Tags: gui, headless

I am half mad and I suddenly had an idea. I don't care that it is very impractical and will cause me trouble, I want it for some reason.

I want to have Linux, without a desktop environment, but be able to run certain apps in a GUI, for example viewing images or video's, or playing games on steam.

If there is some kind of a desktop environment, that just looks like a terminal when not doing anything that requires a gui, I will be fine with that.

Comment: You don't need run a DE (I don't for instance) on the gui. Just find a window manager that suits you and start a terminal (emulator) in full screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of desktop environment and use a window manager only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/how-to-get-rid-of-desktop-environment-and-use-a-window-manager-only)

Answer (score -1):

I recently heard about i3, a minimal desktop environment, that you can customize in any way you like, bu kind of programming it to do what you want.
It does exactly what I want out of the box and even more.